# Trait for composite primary keys in Slick tables?

Tags: postgresql, scala, distinct, slick, slick-pg

I have 2 tables

```scala
case class SimplePKDB(id: Long = 0L)

object SimplePKDB {
  final class SimplePKTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[SimplePKDB](tag, "simple_table") {
    def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  }
}
```

```scala
case class CompositePKDB(id: Long = 0L, registry: String)

object CompositePKDB {
  final class CompositePKTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[CompositePKDB](tag, "composite_table") {
    def id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc)
    def registry: Rep[String] = column[String]("registry")

    def pk = primaryKey(tableName + "_pk", (id, registry))
  }
}
```

I wish to implement a generalized distinctPK method that for `querySimple: Query[SimplePKTable, SimplePKDB, Seq]` unfolds to `querySimple.distinctOn(_.id)` and for `queryComposite: Query[CompositePKTable, CompositePKDB, Seq]` unfolds to `queryComposite.distinctOn(row => (id, registry))`.

I tried creating a trait TableWithPK and extending SimplePKTable and CompositePKTable with it

```scala
trait TableWithPK[V, PK] extends Table[V] {
  def primary: PK
}
```

As `def primary` is not `Rep[_]` (it is either `Rep[Long]`, or `(Rep[Long], Rep[String])), I need to provide` shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, PK, T, _]`in`def distinctPK`.

```scala
def distinctPK[T <: TableWithPK[V, PK], V, PK](query: Query[T, V, Seq])(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, PK, T, _])
: Query[T, V, Seq] = query.distinctOn(_.primary)
```

However this requires implicitly carrying the shape throughout the application, which is not ideal. Is it possible to build it in the TableWithPK or extended table classes (sth like `def shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, PK, TableWithPK[V, PK], _]` inside TableWithPK)? Or this needs a completely different approach?